# Java. Null pointer exception null, while working with RandomAccessFiles

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

im new at using RandomAccessFiles, but I created a file and then re-open the program, before the actual menu appears, the program is supposed to read every object previously saved in the file, im having issues in this section:

```
          if(archivo.exists()){
              int k=0;
               int size;
               size=(int)raf.length()/46;

                objeto array []=new objeto[size];
                  for(int a=0;a<size;a++){
                    System.out.println("This should read the information that was saved in the files previously");

                  array[a].num=raf.readInt();
                  k=k+4;
                  raf.seek(k);
                  array[a].descripcion=raf.readUTF();
                  k=k+30;
                  raf.seek(k);
                  array[a].precio=raf.readFloat();
                  k=k+4;
                  raf.seek(k);
                  array[a].cantidad=raf.readInt();
                  k=k+4;
                  raf.seek(k);
                  array[a].numproveedor=raf.readInt();
                  k=k+4;
                  raf.seek(k);
                }
```

variable "k" is the pointer and should advance every time it reads a variable. but I get the error:" java.lang.Null pointer exception null

Comment: Step one: what's null?

Comment: Its out of the line, but I cant see why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your object for example

```
array[a] = new objeto();
```

and after that you can use it. other wise `array[a]` is `null`

Comment: Wow, I cant believe that I miss that one :l, Thank you so much! :)